# Multiboot Win 7, Ubuntu + Linux on UEFI system

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, uefi

I am quite happy and content today. Yesterday I was able to install Ubuntu 12.10 on my VAIO-S Windows 7 machine from 2012 with UEFI and secure-boot. I've failed several times, but using the secure-remix iso it worked. Then I used boot-repair, which fixed the EFI in a series of automated steps. Very nice!!

But now I wonder if it is possible to install other Linux distros alongside Ubuntu. I want to review them for a blog I have, that's why. And I believe I read somewhere that GPT disks can have up to 128 primary partitions!

So my question is: How do I best do this? Can I just go ahead and install 2 or 3 other distros and then re-run boot repair and have it fix the EFI?

Or is there an other way to do it?

Right now I would like to have a look at Fedora and Zorin, but while I will be using Ubuntu for work, I will be swapping other distros in and out, so that is a concern here.

I hope somebody can tell me how to go about this smartly!!

Comment: I only share the swap and EFI partitions while testing other distros, trying to keep the home folder separated so it won't bug me while trying different versions of the same program for example. The only OS with grub installed is the main working OS, so I can keep track on who is modifying the boot entries; the tested distros only have the kernel installed, without a boot loader, although this might change if you have to report about their boot loaders in your blog.

Comment: Why not just run them as virtual machines? That way you can just delete the machines when not needed any more.

Answer (score 0):

Your multi-boot will not work if you use distributions not compatible with UEFI and SecureBoot. (eg Debian)

Currently, very few Linux distribution have good support of UEFI+SecureBoot.(AFAIK, only Ubuntu12.04.2/12.10 and the last Fedora and derivatives)

Furthermore, I think that Ubuntu and Fedora have different ways to handle UEFI+SecureBoot, so it might not be possible to do a Ubuntu+Fedora multiboot on UEFI/SecureBoot. To workaround this, I recommend you first disable SecureBoot, then run Boot-Repair (this will convert Ubuntu into "Non SecureBoot" mode), then check that Windows+Ubuntu still work, then install Fedora, then run Boot-Repair again.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and reply!

I did not think that the other distros needed to be UEFI & SecureBoot compatible given that Ubuntu would take care of the booting, but I am sure you are right. So that limits the playing field quite a lot for the moment.

I have spent an hour trying to find out about disabling SecureBoot on my mid 2012 VAIO S, and can't find any info in the documentation. And the Insyde BIOS does not have this option. So if anybody knows how to do this, I would be delighted to hear (I assume it is using SecureBoot, but maybe I am wrong?).